# How do I create an action for a button that I created in the GUI Builder on CodenameOne?

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, codenameone

Pretty simply, how and where do I create the ActionListener and action for a button if I created that button in the GUI builder (meaning there is no code in the main java class for it).

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is implement the action to the ActionListener interface.

```
yourButton.addActionListener(e -> System.out.println("button pressed"));
```

For the old GUI builder there is [this](http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---handle-eventsnavigation-in-the-gui-builder--populate-the-form-from-code.html).

In the new GUI builder just select the button then select the component properties, select events and click the action event. Then you can just bind it in GUI as such:

[image]

Comment: I've made some significant edits to your answer both to use Java 8 syntax & remove some "swingisms" e.g. the J stuff. Also clarified a bit in regards to the GUI builders. We have two one of them does indeed hide the components but the new one does not.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog the lambda expresion was a nice touch! haha. Add a lot to the  answer, thanks!